# Фильтр в объекте

Tags: django

Есть запрос к базе:

balans = Accounts.objects.filter(account_name=l, is_deleted="0", is_blocked="0")

получаю результат

```
  balans.valies()

  [{'balance': -8005.10004771231, 'is_deleted': 0L, 'id': 113L, 'is_blocked': 0L,    'account_name': u'adm'}]
```

Вытаскиваем необходимое значение:

```
balans.values().get().get('id',None)
```

Может есть проще вариант как вытащить id, для передачи в другой запрос?

Comment: допишите пожалуйста конкретнее, о чем идет речь, какой второй запрос? Вообще доступ к полям можно организовывать как доступ к полям объекта через точку т.е.: 'some_val.id'

Answer (score 1):

```
for vaue in balans.values():
    value['id'] # можно использовать в запросе
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень понял что нужно сделать, но смею предположить, что нужен список id для сущностей, попавших в отфильтрованный queryset. Тогда можно сделать примерно вот так:

```
balans_id_list = Accounts.objects.filter(account_name=l, is_deleted="0", is_blocked="0").values_list('id', flat=True)
```

и получить сразу список id ([документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)). Потом его можно использовать в каком-то запросе типа

```
something = MyModel.filter(balans__in=list(balans_id_list))
```

Важно использовать list() для производительности, т.к. иначе в запросе получится подзапрос и все может работать довольно медленно.

В вопросе не очень понятно, там один объект должен получиться? Тогда почему просто не взять

```
balans = Accounts.objects.get(account_name=l, is_deleted="0", is_blocked="0").id
```